# SharedPreferences not working

Tags: java, android, string, sharedpreferences

I'm saving two strings fro another activity, when the user logs in, so I can save their data to use another time (Ease of use for the end user). Anyway, I've set up the code and ran it and the strings are not being passed. To make sure, the sharedPreferences are working, I've set up a toast, to see if it matches the info I imputed.

1 Class:

```
uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        String username = uname.getText().toString();

        pword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        String password = pword.getText().toString();

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("key1", username);
        editor.putString("key2", password);
        editor.commit();
```

2nd class:

```
private void Test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String username = settings.getString("key1", null);
        String password = settings.getString("key2", null);
         if(username.equals("irock97")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yaya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
if(username =="irock97")
```

use:

```
if(username.equals("irock97"))
```

to test for `String` equality. With `==` you are testing for object reference equality.

Comment: Hi, It's still not displaying a toast. I updated my code too.

Comment: @user1245593 Call the method `show()` on your `Toast` to actually show it: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yaya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
username == "irock97"
```

with:

```
username.equals("irock97")
```

`==` is used to check if the 2 string references refer to the same object in the memory.

`equals()` is used to check if the 2 string references refer to the same object or 2 different objects with the same string value.

Besides that, you need to check if the string reference is not `null` first:

```
if(username != null && username.equals("irock97"))
```

---

**EDIT:**

Also, you forgot to call `show()` method to show the Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yaya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Hi, It's still not displaying a toast. I updated my code too.

Comment: Thanks! Another person pointed that out, then the toast finally worked. :) Once again, thanks for your generous help. Have a good day, sir.

Answer (score 1):

Remember:

== tests for reference equality.

equals tests for value equality.

so change

```
if(username =="irock97")
```

and use:

```
if(username.equals("irock97"))
```

**But beware of nulls!**

"==" handles null strings fine, but calling ".equals" from a null string will cause an exception:

```
String s1 = null;
String s2 = null;

s1 == s2; // ok, it's true
s1.equals(s2); // throws an exception !
```

EDIT:
You need to call `show()`

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yaya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Hi, It's still not displaying a toast. I updated my code too.

Comment: I never knew that would cause an exception, it's always good to know new rules about Java.

Comment: @user1245593 If `s1` is null, you cannot invoke methods from it.